# Standardizing styles for programmatically generated elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I started creating all elements programmatically and I repeat most of the code for styling the fields (e.g. borderStyle, keyboardType, keyboardAppearance, spellCheckingType, etc.).

What is the most acceptable way of doing this from one place?

Analogue would be CSS - I would define the general styles in one place, and all generated elements would use them automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I kept wanting `UITextField`s with a certain setup, my preferred approach would be to add a factory method to `UITextField`:

```
@implementation UITextField (DHFactory)

+ (instancetype)dh_textField {

    UITextField *textField = [[self alloc] init];

    [textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [textField setSpellCheckingType:UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo];

    return textField;
}

@end
```

I prefixed the category method name, following the advice in Apple’s [*Programming with Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Douglas!